# No solutions with three planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the point in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that these three planes cross:

1. $-x+y+x=4$
2. $2x-y-4x=-2$
3. $-3x+2y+5z=0$.

I do Gauss-Jordan on this system of equation, and find $$0\ 0\ 0 \mid 6$$
So no solutions exist. The planes never cross a point.

Now, I asked myself the question: If I'd got $$0\ 0\ 0\ \mid 0$$
then, would the solution set be a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$? I think yes.

Comment: There are typos in the eq(s).

Comment: It might be a line. It could also maybe be a plane (all three equations could represent the same plane) and I think in that case in the gauss Jordan there would be *two* rows $0,0,0|0$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. Let's consider the following system of equations:
$$\left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            x+2y-2z+3w=2 \\
            2x+4y-3z+4w=5 \\
            5x+10y-8z+11w=12
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$ which is equal to this one (after doing some manipulations on equations):

$$\left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            x+2y-2z+3w=2 \\
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~z-2w=1 \\
            0=0~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (*)
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$ The system is consistent but in second system the number of variables is more than the numbers of equations so the system has infinitely many solutions. Let $y$ and $w$ be our free variables and set $w=b$ and $y=a$ to find out if we can find the general solutions. According to last system we get $z=1+2b$ and $x=4-2a+b$ so $$(4-2a+b,a,1+2b,b)$$. Indeed, if you gave us the system you had in mind in which the third equation was $0=0$, then we would find that possible line.